# How to format an email address line (with name) with PHP?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to generate email messages. The recipient's email address and name are specified by a user. What is the correct way to do this with PHP:

```
$to_header = "To: $name <$email>" # incorrect!
```

I already use a decent method for validating the email addressess (let's not go to that now...), but how do I properly encode $name with eg. QP when needed? For example, if the recipient is called "Foo Bär", I should produce (eg.) something like:

```
To: =?utf-8?Q?Foo_B=C3=A4r?= <foo.bar@example.com>
```

**Update:** Earlier I wasn't using a ready-made mailer such as PHPMailer for other reasons (we already had an external queue system). Anyway, now I'm ending up using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Why isn't it valid? I thought the name part could be any string

Comment: @kemp: It depends on the encoding. E-mail is commonly sent in either 7-bit or 8-bit encoding, which requires characters outside the english alphabet to receive special treatment. Extended reading (loosely related to the topic): http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [`iconv_mime_encode`](http://fi.php.net/iconv_mime_encode) to encode the Subject -header. I presume the same could be used for encoding the name in the To -header as well.

I do, however, as others have, recommend using an existing library or package to handle the encoding for you.

I've used [Mail mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected) available from PEAR. Not perhaps the best out there, but as an alternative to the other ones suggested.

```
var_dump(
    iconv_set_encoding('output_encoding', 'UTF-8'),
    iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8'),
    iconv_set_encoding('input_encoding', 'UTF-8'),
    iconv_mime_encode('To', 'Bäråör Zückefém') .  " <foo@bar.com>"
);
```

Comment: I finally used a combination of iconv_mime_encode() and imap_rfc822_write_address().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`imap_rfc822_write_address`](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_write_address) if it’s available.

Comment: That function seems to take care of quoting (when there is a comma in the name), but not encoding high-bit characters.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use a third party libraby such as PhpMailer or Zend_Mail.
They provide simple methods to set up all these parameters.
They take care of encoding too, and enable some powerful control over sending/authenticating

Otherwise, try going the hardway using the different imap methods :
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.imap.php

Comment: I am using PhpMailer and still have to convert my recipient names and subjects manually! I do it like this:
``$mail->AddAddress($toAddress, "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($toName)."?=");``
and
``$mail->Subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";``

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it (with a bit of overkill):

```
function check_referrer($referrers) {
    if (count($referrers)) {
        $found = false;
        $temp = explode("/",getenv("HTTP_referrer"));
        $referrer = $temp[2];
            if ($referrer == "") {
            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_referrer'];
            list($remove, $stuff) = split('//', $referrer, 2);
            list($home, $stuff) = split('/', $stuff, 2);
            $referrer = $home;
        }
            for ($x = 0; $x < count($referrers); $x++) {
            if (eregi ($referrers[$x], $referrer)) {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if ($referrer == "") {
            $found = false;
        }
        if (!$found){
            error_log("[Store Checkout] Illegal Referrer. (".getenv("HTTP_referrer").")", 0);
            return "<div id='error'><p>You are coming from an <strong>unauthorized domain.</strong></p>\r\n"."\t<ul>\r\n".$error_list."\t</ul>\r\n"."</div>\r\n";
        }
        return $found;
    } else {
    return "<div id='error'><p>You are coming from an <strong>unauthorized domain.</strong></p>\r\n"."\t<ul>\r\n".$error_list."\t</ul>\r\n"."</div>\r\n";
    }
} /* end function check_referrer */

function mail_it($content, $subject, $sender, $recipient) {
    $referrers = array("example.com");

    $authorizedDomain = check_referrer($referrers);
    if($authorizedDomain === FALSE) {
        return $authorizedDomain;
    }
    $sender = remove_headers($sender);
    $recipient = remove_headers($recipient);

    if($content !== FALSE && $subject !== FALSE && $sender !== FALSE && $recipient !== FALSE) {
        $headers = "from: ".$sender."\r\n"; 
        mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
    }
    return;
} /* end function mail_it */

$content = "email body content";
$subject = "email subject";
$sender = "Your Name <yname@example.com>";
$recipient = $name . "<" . $email . ">";


mail_it($content, $subject, $sender, $recipient);
```

Comment: I can't remember where I found the `check_referrer` code, but it works well.

Comment: Sorry, but this all seems quite unrelated, and doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If I understand your question, the line at the bottom addresses your question (the rest is needed to send the email securely): `$recipient = $name . "<" . $email . ">";`. But then again, trying to read between the lines – if you are really asking about character encoding, and not formatting the email address with a name – then no, I did not address that issue (as the question does not seem to directly ask for that information).